# How to grab the full URL in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, url, siteurl

When writing a plugin is there a Craft request to grab the entire url? I want to grab everything including http://domain.com/uri preferably without writing my own function.

I see [getUrl](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getUrl) but `craft()->request->url` only returns 'uri' of http://domain.com/uri.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
craft()->request->getHostInfo().craft()->request->getRequestUri();
```

Which will return the host name with the schema it's using (http:// or https://) as well as any URI after the host including any querystring parameters.